# typescript cannot infer subset of keys of object from usage

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I'm working on algebraic data types in ts and stuck with typing the match function. Simplified version of the problem is demonstrated below:

```
let rec = { a: 'a', b: 1 };

// just captures type of 'rec' and then reuses the type for eval
const makeEval = <Record>(rec: Record) => <
  Res,
  K extends keyof Record = keyof Record
>(
  val: Record,
  cases:
    | Cases<Record, Res>
    | (Cases<Record, Res, K> & { else: (r: Record) => Res })
): Res => (undefined as any) as Res;

export type Cases<Record, Res, K extends keyof Record = keyof Record> = {
  [T in K]: (value: Record[T]) => Res
};

const evalMyRecord = makeEval(rec);

// this is fine
const a = evalMyRecord(rec, { a: s => s, b: n => n.toString() });

// err
const b = evalMyRecord(rec, { a: s => s, else: _ => 'why err?' });
// Property 'b' is missing in type '{ a: (s: string) => string; else: (_: { a: string; b: number; }) => string; }'.

// requires explicit subset
const b_ = evalMyRecord<string, 'a'>(rec, {
  a: s => s,
  else: _ => 'but explicit a is fine'
});

// full set is fine
const c = evalMyRecord(rec, {
  a: s => s,
  b: n => 'n',
  else: _ => 'fine too'
});
```

So I want to express a type that is either has all keys of Record or any subset of it + {else} case.

I know that there is a solution with Partial:

```
type EvalCases<Record, Res> =
  | Cases<Record, Res>
  | (Partial<Cases<Record, Res>> & { else: (r: Record) => Res });

const b = evalMyRecord(rec, { a: s => s, else: _ => 'works' });

const b2 = evalMyRecord(rec, {
  a: s => s,
  b: undefined,
  else: _ => 'also works but weird'
});
```

But having: {b: undefined} looks a bit off. I want a compiler error if any case is not a proper function (if possible).

Any suggestions on typescript magic?

NOTE: conceptually close (but no the same) to [Typescript cannot infer correct argument types for an object of functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49014814/typescript-cannot-infer-correct-argument-types-for-an-object-of-functions).

Comment: Regarding _"But having: {b: undefined} looks a bit off."_, partial means you can _omit_ properties entirely. It creates a type where all properties are optional

Comment: Yes. It is a suitable workaround but I would prefer having compiler error with {b: undefined}. So it is either a proper function or no prop at all

Answer (score 1):

The following solution allows you to have either `Cases<Record, Res>` or any subset of `Cases<Record, Res>` plus the `else` property.

```
type EnforcingPartial<T> = {
    [key in keyof T]: { [subKey in key]: T[key]; }
}[keyof T];

type EvalCases<Record, Res> = Cases<Record, Res> |
    (EnforcingPartial<Cases<Record, Res>> & { else: (r: Record) => Res });

const b = evalMyRecord(rec, { a: s => s, else: _ => 'works' });

const b2 = evalMyRecord(rec, {
    a: s => s,
    b: undefined, // ERROR HERE, b is incompatible
    else: _ => 'also works but weird'
});
```

Comment: That's really cool. However there is a failing case
```typescript
const c = evalMyRecord(rec, {
  a: s => s,
  b: n => 1, 
  else: _ => 'fine too'
});
```
n=> 1 isn't checked for return type (should be string)